# Passing string parameter with alphabetic characters to a javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, string, parameters

i tried to call a javascript function onclick event of button  with a parameter string parameter consisting of all alphabetic characters (eg: test_function("1","10","fsdadfa");) and failed to get it worked. But when i changed the alphabetic characters with all numeric ones (eg:test_function("2","14","12234");) it worked.

```
msg += '<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" class="okbtn" value="OK" onclick="test_function('+id+','+user_id+',\'' +code+ '\');"/>';
var phtml3 = '<div style="display: none;"><div id="share" style="overflow:auto;">'+msg+'</div></div>'; 
$('#my_div').append(phtml3);
```

Any body know why it happened? if so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks sloppy, instead of using onclick, why not just attach an event listener to that element?

```
<script>
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
   test_function(id, user_id, code);
});
</script>
```

Saves you the pain of fiddling with escaping strings and harder to find code in your html page.